# How to persist object to database outside of a controller using Symfony 3 with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to separate data access from my controllers in a Symfony 3 application. Symfony allows Doctrine mediated DB queries to be made via a repository class that extends the EntityRepository class, but I'm having trouble finding a way to *persist* objects to the DB outside of a class that inherits from the controller base class.  Simply put: How can I persist an Entity object to a DB via Doctrine outside of a controller in Symfony?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you mean to persist the obj from within the controller method? if so - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database

Comment: Please add some code to show where do you want to persist your data.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options ,

Say that the class you want to persist objects with a class  named `DBManager`

1. Define `DBManager` as a service and inject doctrine entity manager into this class. [This thread may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678106/how-can-i-inject-doctrine-into-symfony2-service)
2. Make `DBManger` extends `ContainerAware`, like that you will already have entity manager along with other services like mailer, logger, etc.  [Take a look at this answer for more details on how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17126835/1545904)